# Video container responsiveness

Tags: html, css

I have built a small mock website to play around with video backgrounds. However it breaks at >1900px wide and fails to resize when shrinking the viewport.

Here is the [github page](https://freshnewkicks.github.io/Inertia/) and [here is the repo containing source files](https://github.com/freshnewkicks/Inertia)

Here is the HTML for the container (Which is part of the header):

```
    <div class="header-wrapper">
    <header class="header">
        Inertia <span class="header-span-sub">Robotics</span>
    </header>
</div>

<header class="header-video">
    <div class="header-video-container">
        <video src="vid/abstract_line1.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.header-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -150;
  filter: invert(0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements need `width` defined if it's to fill the viewport.

Add `width: 100%` to `.header-video`

Also add `width: 100%` to the `video` too, since it's using the video's own dimensions to determine the size (1920px wide)

Comment: Great that did the trick. However now when shrinking the viewport it maintains it's aspect ratio and cuts the bottom off. [Shown here](https://i.gyazo.com/6b1264cb8f0e5b2bcc44b4929e89abb0.png)